# Module error with ng.django.forms

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs

I was following django-angular docs but I can't figure how to load ng.django.forms.

I tried in myapp.js:

```
app = angular.module('myapp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ng.django.forms',
    ... other dependencies
]);
```

and I get the following error:

```
Failed to instantiate module myapp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=n...)
at Error (native)
at http://27.0.0.1:8000/static/lib/angular/angular.min.js:6:449
at http://27.0.0.1:8000/static/lib/angular/angular.min.js:30:1
at Array.forEach (native)
at q (http://27.0.0.1:8000/static/lib/angular/angular.min.js:7:274)
at e (http://27.0.0.1:8000/static/lib/angular/angular.min.js:29:115)
at http://27.0.0.1:8000/static/lib/angular/angular.min.js:29:192
at Array.forEach (native)
at q (http://27.0.0.1:8000/static/lib/angular/angular.min.js:7:274)
at e (http://27.0.0.1:8000/static/lib/angular/angular.min.js:29:115
```

Without ng.django.forms, it loads correctly but I'd like to use it... I'm using Angular 1.2.25 if some names have changed..

Comment: Are you [including the js file](http://django-angular.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration.html#bound-forms) for django-angular?

Comment: And I feel so dumb right now! Godammnit! Thanks!!